# clang 3.1 with libc++on ubuntu 12.04, iostream not found

Tags: ubuntu, clang, libc++

I am trying to compile a C++ program using clang which I installed using a packaged version here https://launchpad.net/~eudoxos/+archive/llvm-3.1.  This is the command:

```
clang++   -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -g -v -c main.cpp
```

And I get this as the result:

```
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include/c++/v1"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/bin/../lib/clang/3.1/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory ""
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
/usr/local/include
/usr/include/clang/3.1/include
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/include

main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
#include <iostream>
```

As you can see, it is not searching in the correct include directory, /usr/include/c++/4.6.
But I think the issue is deeper than that.  Even when I force it to search in that directory, I get this:

```
In file included from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/iostream:38:10: fatal error: 'bits/c++config.h' file not found
#include <bits/c++config.h>
```

And that file doesn't exist in that area. I am thinking maybe libc++ is missing, but before I make a huge mess trying to compile libc++ from source (which I doubt will work) since I cannot find any dedicated libc++ ubuntu package, I was hoping you guys could help out.

Thanks very much!

Comment: Just an update, I recently switched over to Arch Linux and still have the same error and I am using clang 3.1 from the Arch extra repo

Comment: 'Fedora19' and the same problem

Comment: @DanB91 i am also facing the same issue, do you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think I ever found a solution.  I think as I last resort I attempted to compile libc++, which became too much of a hassle.

I eventually just ended up switching to GCC.  Shame that this error is still an issue.  

Sorry I couldn't be of more help.  But I'd suggest trying to compile the libc++ if you want to take on that endeavor and post back here

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, as far as I know you currently need to build libc++ (and possibly libc++abi as well) from source  to use -stdlib=libc++ with clang on Linux.

Comment: Any instructions for this?

Comment: @JaredBurrows This comment is very old. These days, on most modern linux distros you should be able to install libc++ via the package manager

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am having an issue with TravisCI using Clang.

Comment: @JaredBurrows I see, yeah the Travis environment is really dated: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. That probably doesn't have clang as you would want it. However, you should be able in your .travis.yml to install clang and libc++ from the LLVM dpkg repository, following the instructions for "precise": http://llvm.org/apt/

Comment: Alright. I have been trying something similar and I have install clang++-3.6 easily but I need to install the libc++ as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

sudo apt-get install -y clang-3.6 lldb-3.6 libc++-dev libc++abi-dev

https://gist.github.com/fyears/745da3cf6b19dbff3d0e